# How does the Toad Totem work when playing as Plague Knight?

Tags: shovel-knight-pocket-dungeon

In **Shovel Knight: Pocket Dungeon** the *Toad Totem* is a relic which makes it so that "Attacks poison foes." That's pretty straight forward for most characters, but when playing as Plague Knight, your attacks already inflict poisons on foes:

> Poison your foes with attacks and bombs!

So I'm not really sure how this ability would work when playing as Plague Knight. My assumption would be that it would just inflict double poison on foes, but I'm not really sure. I'm also not good enough yet that I feel like blowing money on the relic if it turns out it doesn't really do anything at all.

**How does the Toad Totem relic work when playing as Plague Knight?**

Comment: So I just decided to grab it on a run where I knew I was about to die anyway, and it seemed like it really did absolutely nothing... so now I'm very curious to know if this relic is truly useless on PLague Knight, or if I'm just missing some hidden interaction.